# ES6-shim from Angular2 conflicts with Typescript lib.es6.d.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to compile my Angular2 application written in Typescript into ES6 code planning compile it to ES5 lately using Babel. But I'm getting the error:

```
node_modules/angular2/typings/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts(6,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
<...>
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(3841,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
<...>
```

I have tried to solve this problem adding directive `noLib` to my `tsconfig.json`, but one of angular files (`zone.d.ts`) need to import `es6-shim.d.ts` with

```
/// <reference path="es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts" />
```

and it conflicts with main typescript ES6 library (`lib.es6.d.ts`).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5395

Comment: are you sure you are compiling to ES5? this error usually shows when you try to compile angular2 to es6, because then TSC will provide it's own es6 library. Check the target in tsconfig.json.

Comment: @toskv I'm trying to compile project to ES6, because I want to use `Symbol.iterator` that can be used only through Babel compilation.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, so, it is a bug? I thought it can be solved by some settings magic, but if it is a bug, it seems I cannot do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Lodin, I don't know. I only use Dart and don't understand any of the discussion in the issue. I just remembered seeing the issue and thought this looks related.

Comment: isn't this issue being caused by the fact that there are 2 es6-shim.d.ts files being referenced during compilation? Sounds like it's the same as this issue https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5015

Comment: @xmojmr, yes, thanks.

Comment: @toskv, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5973 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4882 is closer, I think. It does not resolve my problem, but gives me a way to explore, thanks.

Comment: From my point of view this isn't even something to do with angular, it's bad dependency management by the compiler. :(

Comment: also if you follow the links in that issue you'll end up to an issue that's still open for angular, so it's definitely not solved. :(

Comment: @toskv, yes, I agree. `<reference>` is a completely terrible idea, it does not consider namespaces and produces such problems. ES6-like import is much more acceptable, in my opinion, but somehow it cannot be applied to `d.ts` files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100287/discussion-between-toskv-and-lodin).

Comment: @toskv, yes, unfortunately, not solved yet. But Angular is still in beta, it may be solved lately, I hope.

Comment: you get the same issue with the es6 imports. the root problem is relative file references, while compiling projects with a global scope that does not allow duplicate definitions. That, combined with allowing definitions to be located in the node-modules folder results in a total mess. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this in your tsconfig.json?:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

btw why are you using babel if you are already using typescript? they're both compilers you only need one. If you have your code written in typescript, typescript compiler will compile it into js, you can't recompile it because it's already compiled. Just choose the target compiler option whether you'll use es5 or es6 syntax if you compile it using es6 syntax make sure you add an es6 shim to your app for when it runs on browsers that don't yet recognize es6.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. Moreover, it is a root of problem, because `es6-shim` conflicts with `lib.es6.d.ts`, which is using when `--target es6` is set. About Babel - I use it because typescript itself cannot compile es6 generators and iterators like babel does.

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this & still target es5? I need code to output to 5 not 6. This does make the errors go away though. So having es6 shim in your app will make it all work fine then?